# C++ String subcript out of range issue

Tags: c++

I'm a student currently studying C++ and I have a problem with a code that I am trying to create. The code I am supposed to create is meant to find the hamming distance of 2 words that the user will input. (For e.g "Ironman" and "Iron" hamming distance is "3")

However, I ran into an error when I tried compiling and I can't seem to find out what the problem is. The error of "String subscript out of range" keeps popping up if the first input is longer than the second input.(It only fails to work when I try to input "Spiderman Ironman". Shorter words such as "Sean Sea" works fine.) If the second input is longer than the first input, OR if both the inputs are the same length, the entire code works fine.

```
string str1;
string str2;

cout << "Question 1" << endl;
cout << "Input two words (separated by space or enter) : ";

cin >> str1;
cin >> str2;

int count = hamming_distance(str1, str2);

cout << "> Hamming distance between \"" << str1 << "\" and \"" << str2 << "\" is " << count << endl;



int i;
int firstLength = str1.length();
int secondLength = str1.length();
int thirdLength;
int counter = 0;

//if the longest word is first string (Where the issue is causing)
if (firstLength > secondLength)
{
    thirdLength = firstLength - secondLength;
    for (i = 0; i < firstLength; i++)
    {
        if (str1[i] != str2[i])
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < thirdLength; i++)
    {
        counter++;
    }
}

//if the longest word is second string
else if (secondLength > firstLength)
{
    thirdLength = secondLength - firstLength;
    for (i = 0; i < secondLength; i++)
    {
        if (str1[i] != str2[i])
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < thirdLength; i++)
    {
        counter++;
    }
}

//if both words have the same length
else if (firstLength == secondLength)
{
    for (i = 0; i < firstLength; i++)
    {
        if (str1[i] != str2[i])
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
}

return counter;
```

It would be greatly appreciated if y'all could help me find out what the actual problem is with my code. Thank you!

Comment: You're initialising both `firstLength` and `secondLength` to `str1.length()`

Comment: If you make the first loop `for (int i= 0; i < std::min(firstLength, secondLength); i++)` and the second loop be `for (int i=std::min(firstLength,secondLength); i<std::max(firstLength,secondLength); i++)` then you can get rid of all the tests for which is greater.  You should also make `firstLength` and `secondLength` be const.

Comment: Alternatively, replace the second loop with `counter += std::max(firstLength, secondLength) - std::min(firstLength, secondLength);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialise your variables correctly:

```
int firstLength = str1.length();
int secondLength = str2.length();
```

You're also determining that one string is bigger than another, then proceeding to access elements in the shorter string according to the length of the longer one, which is giving you the subscript out of range error.  You need to revise the tests when firstLength > secondLength and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you, I did not see that! However, even after making the changes, the error still occurs, and as it turns out, the error occurs when the second input is bigger than the first input as well, it seems that this occurs when the two strings are long

Comment: Thank you Ian, your explanation was extremely clear and it fixed the issue I was having. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: No problem.  Thank me by accepting the answer and upvoting ;)